# Skyrim SE - Mod Organizer Error

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I've recently chosen to use Mod Organizer in conjunction with Skyrim Special Edition, so that I have a separate launcher for both Oldrim and SE. I'm currently loading it with mods, but I'm having some trouble loading the Character Creation Overhaul.

Here is the error message:
"Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users(Username)\Desktop\All of the Everything\Games\Skyrim Folder\Mod Organizer\NCC\GameModes\SkyrimSE.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

If I click through, I get another error message that reads as follows: installation failed (errorcode 5)

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it? I'm not sure what to do, I tried searching for the answers and found a fair amount of language I don't really understand since I'm horrible with programming. I will provide a modlist on request.

EDIT: There's a second window that opens behind those that has a progress bar and a message that reads: Running external installer. Based on Nexus Mod Manager by Black Tree Gaming Ltd.

Comment: Do you have Skyrim Script Extender installed? You can actually find this in Steam and all you have to do is install it and run it once. This allows advanced scripts to run parallel with Skyrim's scripts.